# kube-proxy reports wrong ip address

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

In my kubernetes cluster, each node is a virtualbox vm with two NICs, eth0 for NAT and eth1 for Host-Local communicating.

`kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide` shows

[image]

We can see k8s-3 and k8s-4 reports correct IPs while k8s-2 doesn't.

I've tried to add `--bind-address=192.168.99.202` in `k8s-2`'s `kube-proxy.yaml` but it just don't work.

Anyone has any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44702

Problem solved by passing `--node-ip=` to kubelet.

Answer (score 0):

use --hostname-override in your kubelet and set it to the ip.  it will make your name of your node into your ip but it will have the correct address. i had this problem on my test cluster (vagrant and virtualbox) and i had to make that change. I also set the hostname-overide in my kube-proxy.  i was troubleshooting issues with my kube-proxy and at one point i made that change but thats not what ultimately resolved it so i am unsure if really needed.

if your running flannel, don't forget to make sure its using the correct --iface since it likes to use eth0.